# Configuring NAT on a Thomson cable modem/router

Tags: networking, router, nat

I have a simple cable modem (Thomson TWG870).

1. I've looked in the manual, but there is no option to select the NAT type the router uses. Can I conclude that the only - and default - mode is port-based?
2. The computers on the LAN can access the internet by default (without any configuration required to the router). Does this mean the NAT functionality is enabled by default?

Answer (score 2):

It is an IPv4 router, so it has to NAT to provide WAN access to the LAN devices.

The only way to bypass the NAT is to set up DMZ to point to one of your machines but in most cases port-forwarding would be sufficient.  Since you don't mention any specific need, I can't assume on your requirements for this.

Comment: Sorry but Your answer doesn't target my questions absolutelly. I know that for WAN initiated connections i have to explicitable setup port-forwarding but i've asked about LAN initiated connectins. If In such a case port-forwarding is enabled by default (without any setup)?

Comment: The fact that you included `NAT` in **both** of your questions lead me to assume that you knew what it meant.  Connections initiated internally **will** indeed get forwarded back to the initiator automatically.